# Diazo coupling of α-naphthol

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

Why does coupling of α-naphthol take place at δ-position (*para* to $\ce{-OH}$) rather than the β-position (*ortho* to $\ce{-OH}$)?

In the case of [β-naphthol](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97067/mechanism-of-formation-of-2-naphthol-red-dye-aka-sudan-1), we consider the aromaticity of the entire compound to decide the position.

Aromaticity is not disturbed even when the attack takes place at the *ortho* position. So I don't find any reason for the diazo compound to not attack there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regioselectivity in coupling reactions of α-naphthol](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/138267/regioselectivity-in-coupling-reactions-of-%ce%b1-naphthol)

Comment: In his picture, the OP says that ortho position is sterically hindered. I don't find any reason why.

Comment: OH can cause steric hinderance. Also, there is much greater -I effect on ortho compared to para..

Comment: We dont consider ortho effect in phenols because of the small size of OH. Why here then?

Comment: Take second case.. not first